# Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost'

Tags: server, dpkg, mysql

I just noticed this message in my syslog and have been unable to find a solution.  Most solutions I am finding are all about recovering the root password (which I know and can use successfully) instead of getting the password correct for the 'debian-sys-maint' user.  The one solution I found raised an even stranger question:  Why is my system confused about what version of MySQL is installed?

When I log in as root I see this:

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 4
Server version: 5.7.23 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

(and a bit more).  So I tried to reconfigure the server (as the article I found recommended) and saw this:

```
user@cpu:~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7
dpkg-query: package 'mysql-server-5.7' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: mysql-server-5.7 is not installed
```

Being confused by the fact that mysql reports its server version as 5.7 but dpkg thinks mysql-server-5.7 is not installed, I thought I would try earlier versions and found this:

```
user@cpu:~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.6
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: mysql-server-5.6 is broken or not fully installed
```

So now I have two questions:

1. What is the proper procedure for correcting the error shown in the subject of this post?  (I might be able to get it working by hand, using the root mysql user and a text editor, but that doesn't 'feel' right.)
2. How do I get dpkg in sync with mysql as far as what is installed and running?  (FWIW, mysql was upgraded during one (or more) Ubuntu distribution upgrades from one LTS version to the next.  I am at 18.x now, but started with 12.x years ago.)

I apologize for not being an expert.  We are a tiny company with a tiny web server that I inherited while my primary job is writing code for Windows.

EDIT:  Adding output from a suggested command.

```
user@cpu:~$ sudo dpkg -l mysql*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
un  mysql          <none>       <none>       (no description available)
dpkg-query: no packages found matching mysql56.tar.bz2
dpkg-query: no packages found matching mysql.tar.bz2
```

It looks to me like dpkg thinks mysql is not installed, by mysql thinks v5.7 is running.

Comment: You should not have tried to install the lower version, but run `sudo dkpg -l mysql*`

Comment: It did not occur to me that dpkg-reconfigure would actually INSTALL anything.  I thought I was just asking it to try to reconfigure different versions and that it would work with the one it installed.